# How to pass currently iterated element (this) into setTimeout inside .each() function?

Tags: jquery, variables, each, settimeout

I'm trying to iterate through each `caption-element` inside `caption` div using `each()` function, get `captionin`, `captionout` and `delayout` attributes, next `removeClass` of that element given in `captionout` attribute (without checking if the class has been already added or not) and `addClass` to that element given in `captionin` attribute. That's easy and works perfectly.

Next I'm trying to reverse the whole process of adding and removing classes taken from `captionin` and `captionout` attributes but this time to delay it by a amount of time given in `delayout` attribute (by using `setTimeout()` function). And it doesn't work.

The whole ide is to give every iterated element it's own setTimeout delay taken from `delayout` attribute.

Every help for a complete rookie much appreciated :)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caption">
    <div id="1" class="caption-container">
          <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="fadeInUp" captionout="bounceOut" delayout="2000">Caption 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="caption-container">
          <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="swing" captionout="fadeOutDown" delayout="4000">Caption 2</h1>
          <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="bounceInUp" captionout="lightSpeedOut" delayout="3000">Caption 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="caption-container">
          <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="bounceInUp" captionout="rotateOutUpLeft" delayout="2500">Caption 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('.caption .caption-element').each(function () {
        var captionin = jQuery(this).attr('captionin');
        var captionout = jQuery(this).attr('captionout');
        var delayout = jQuery(this).attr('delayout');
        jQuery(this).removeClass(captionout).addClass(captionin);
        setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass(captionin).addClass(captionout);
        }, delayout, captionin, captionout);
});
```

PS, ask question in comment before downvoting please, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you can explain a little more about what does this code do? what is the objective, what are you trying to do => As a functionality.

Comment: @Joraid I'm trying to iterate through each 'caption-element' inside 'caption' DIV, get it's `captionin`, `captionout` and `delayout` attributes, then remove and add class ot the currently iterated element using 'captionin' and 'captionout', then do the reverse process of removing and adding class after a delay given in `delayout`. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I meant, why are you doing this? Design perspective.

Comment: I'm trying to make captions for a slider to disappear each in different time. Everything is sorted except of different out animations times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

1- Scope. `this` is not the same `this` in different functions. [More about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  I solved this by capturing the `JQuery(this)` in a variable and use it across the code. Therefore, this won't give me surprise when I want to access the selected element `$elem` from somewhere else in the code.

2- I assume `setTimeout` needs a number as a value of time units. You are passing a string.

```js
jQuery('.caption .caption-element').each(function() {
  var $elem = jQuery(this);


  var captionin = $elem.attr('captionin');
  var captionout = $elem.attr('captionout');
  var delayout = $elem.attr('delayout');

  console.log("Before: " + $elem.attr("class"));
  $elem.removeClass(captionout).addClass(captionin);

  setTimeout(function(captionin, captionout) {

    $elem.removeClass(captionin).addClass(captionout);
    console.log("After:" + $elem.attr("class"));

  }, Number(delayout), captionin, captionout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<div class="caption">
  <div id="1" class="caption-container">
    <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="fadeInUp" captionout="bounceOut" delayout="2000">Caption 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="caption-container">
    <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="swing" captionout="fadeOutDown" delayout="4000">Caption 2</h1>
    <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="bounceInUp" captionout="lightSpeedOut" delayout="3000">Caption 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="caption-container">
    <h1 class="caption-element animated" captionin="bounceInUp" captionout="rotateOutUpLeft" delayout="2500">Caption 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
Before: caption-element animated
Before: caption-element animated
Before: caption-element animated
Before: caption-element animated
After:caption-element animated bounceOut
After:caption-element animated rotateOutUpLeft
After:caption-element animated lightSpeedOut
After:caption-element animated fadeOutDown
```

Comment: Yes, Actually I made it work myself before you posted this answer, The only difference was i added `var $this = this` and then passed `jQuery($this)...` inside setTimeout, but effect is the same. And passing `delayout`as is into setTimeout works without type juggling. I obviously accept your answer. Thank you very much for your effort! Best regards.

Comment: So the solution descended on us at the same time.  Sometimes you need to say it loud to see it. And always console.log out stuff to see what is happening. 
Best of luck.